# How to create a rule-based access control unit for different user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, software-design

I'm trying to implement a Role-based Access Control Unit for my app but don't know how to do it given my constraints.

I use Devise for my sign in/up operations. I have only one model User but every user has a different `user_type`. I have eight unique user types with different authentication levels (integer).

These are the constraints on how users interact with the site:

1. Users with higher authentication levels can perform their related user types with lower authentication levels functions, i.e., access to their related controllers and do stuff.
2. Not every user type with the same authentication levels can access the same controller: `user1` with `auth_level = 2` can access to controller `C1` but `user2` with the same `auth_level = 2` can access controller `C2`. Other way to say it is that they are doing different jobs at the same level.
3. Is there any gem to implement such things? I've looked into [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) it does not satisfy my needs.
4. If there is no gem, what approach/design do you suggest to implement such access control unit?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. You haven't told us enough about your environment or needs, so your question is broad. You're asking us to give you recommendations for off-site resources, which is off-topic too. Instead, you need to do the research and try things, then decide what works best for you, write code, and then, if you have a problem, ask a specific question about that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked this question a couple of days ago, for some time I wonder around and evaluating available gems, suitable for my purpose but I couldn't find any `simple`, `easy-to-use` and `lightweight` enough to import it into my application; So I accepted the fight and wrote my own gem named [ACU (Access Control Unit)](https://github.com/noise2/rails-acu), which satisfies my constraints in the question + it's very lightweight and easy-to-use and general for any purposes.

In this gem, every request is either gets passed through or not, and the access rules can cover any aspect of the rails app. the following is an example of the rules set, for more details you can see the documentation provided at [here](https://github.com/noise2/rails-acu).

```
# config/initializers/acu_rules.rb
Acu::Rules.define do
  # anyone makes a request could be count as everyone!
  whois :everyone { true }

  whois :admin, args: [:user] { |c| c and c.user_type == :ADMIN.to_s }

  whois :client, args: [:user] { |c| c and c.user_type == :CLIENT.to_s }

  # any request that doesn't match with a rule will be denied by default; 
  # but this can be configured to not to!

  # the default namespace
  namespace do
    controller :home, except: [:some_secret_action] do
      allow :everyone
    end
    controller :home do
      allow [:admin, :client], on: [:some_secret_action]
    end
  end

  # the admin namespace
  namespace :admin do
    allow :admin

    controller :contact, only: [:send_message] do
      allow :everyone
    end

    controller :contact do
      action :support {
        allow :client
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use Route Constraints (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) for implementing the controller access.

Using `request.env["warden"].authenticate` you can the authenticate the current user for the request inside the `matches?` method in your constraint class. If you use `request.env["warden"].authenticate!` you will even redirect the user to the login page, or display an appropriate error message (depending on your setup).

Comment: Please don't make recommendations; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341780/128421